JAWS reading the error message twice in lightning input LWC
JAWS reads the error message on the lightning input twice, because of the presence of both aria-errormessage and aria-describedby attributes. Values for both attributes are the same.
How to resolve this and make JAWS read the error message only once. I have tried to remove one of the attributes, but I cannot access the "input element" from the DOM.


If I were you, I'd ask at the Trailblazer LWC group too.

That sounds like a bug to me. Do you mind opening a support case with Salesforce?
